# CKeditor Making percentage as default in width

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, ckeditor.net

I am using CKeditor, in creating Table by default the width is taking as px. i need only in percentage. Is there any option to make it as percentage always.

for example if i enter the width as 80 it has to take it as 80%. But now it is taking as 80px

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make that change in your `config.xml` file like this     `width['default'] = "80%";`,

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
      var diagName = ev.data.name;
      var diagDefn = ev.data.definition;

      if(diagName === 'table') {
        var infoTab = diagDefn.getContents('info');

        var width = infoTab.get('txtWidth');
        width['default'] = "80%";
      }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: On doing this by default the value is loaded as 80% .  we use this code to override the value for the below function.   "default":a.filter.check("table{width}")?500>q.getSize("width")?"100%":500:0..                            this was the actual code available in ckeditor.js   by default 500px will be loaded. On entering the code which yu provide 80% will be default.       But my query is i need to restrict the user to have only % not to enter other units

Comment: My requirement is , i need only percentage need to be entered. if i enter 50 the value need to be 50% it should nt be 50px

Comment: can some one reply for this ?

Comment: The above code resets the width from `80px` to `80%`, and when you modify it to someother value (for e.g from the present `80%` to `100`) it would still take percentage not pixel. Please check

Comment: No luck , it change to px only ,cssLength:function(){var a=/^-?\d+\.?\d*px$/,f;return function(b){f=CKEDITOR.tools.trim(b+"")+"px";return a.test(f)?
f:b||""}} this code change it to px can you try it

Comment: Can some one help on this ?